# Passing volatile array to function in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, volatile

How do I pass a **volatile** array into a function in c++?

```
volatile uint8_t* array[16];

void processArray(const uint8_t** inputArray) <--- ????
{
    // process each element in the array
}

void main()
{
     processArray(array); <-- ???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `volatile` to your parameter:

```
void processArray(volatile const uint8_t** inputArray)
```

Plus, as you are using `const` for your parameter, then you need to pass a const pointer as well, which means you might need something like:

```
 processArray((volatile const uint8_t**)array);
```